# Android Robotium test - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robotium

I'm having problems with Robotium being unable to find my app at runtime.

Just to be clear, I've seen a few similar questions on SO however, they seem to revolve around the Robotium *Solo* class not being found at runtime (or some other 3rd party lib). However, this is slightly different as my Robotium tests can't find the *project under test*.

The tests are in a separate project which has a dependency on my app project. There are no problems at compile-time but when I try to run the tests I get...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests 
....
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.mobile.activity.RegisterUserScreen
```

Where RegisterUserScreen is an activity in my app. This happens on the device and the emulator.

I'm building / running in IntelliJ 12.1.4, against Android 4.1.2 and I see the same result  when I attempt to run the test from the command line.

Probably worth pointing out that running *adb shell pm list instrumentation* from the command line returns the correct instrumentation...

```
instrumentation:com.myapp.mobile.test.system/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunn
er (target=com.myapp.mobile)
```

Thanks in advance,

Neil.

Comment: Sir, can you please check dependent project is referenced correctly once again.

Comment: It is referenced correctly. I'm building and deploying through IntelliJ and there are no compile errors in the tests (therefore the test project can see the app classes). The current scope of the depedency is 'provided' - which is correct. I changed it to 'compile' just as a sanity test and, as expected, it failed with an error 'class ref in preverified class resolved to unexpected implementation' - which, evidently, is expected when you have a 'compile' dependency between your test and app project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you try to put the fullpath `com.myapp.mobile.activity.RegisterUserScreen` in app Manifest.xml (instead of the usual .RegisterUserScreen) ?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make any difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your device go to settings->apps and check whether in installed or running application list name of your testing application name is present. If you find it there then uninstall the testing app as well as your original app (which has to be tested). Many times it happens that either because of different versions/signature mismatch test-application fails to find the target application.

Comment: This seems to have worked! A while back I refactored the name of the test project. When I looked under settings today I could see that *both* the test projects (old and new) were still visible. I uninstalled both *and* the app-under-test, did a full re-build and it is now working. As you say, seems to be a problem with the clashing signatures. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, to anyone else seeing the same problem and stumbling across this question on SO I would recommend being careful about exactly which dependencies your app exports to your test project. Remove them all and then only add those which you absolutely need. Add them 1 at a time, performing a full re-build after each one. My problem was caused by the test project refactoring (as indicated in kamal_prd's answer) however, I think the problems may have been exacerbated by exporting unecessary libs.

Comment: Many times it happens that clashing signature causes problem while testing the app. So, it is recommended to uninstall the target app as well as testing app after doing any kind of changes in either of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Create your run configuration as an "Android Tests" not as "JUnit"